# How to collect output from pipes to file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have a producer pipe and I have used the print pipe. I would like to write the output to a file.
If I use Control.Data.sinkFile, like

```
test2file = runPipe $ CB.sinkFile "testOutput" <+< traverseTree fn3
```

I get a type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Pipe
                                b0 void-0.5.8:Data.Void.Void m0 r0'
            with actual type `Data.Conduit.Internal.Pipe
                                l0 Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString o0 r1 m1 r1'
In the return type of a call of `sinkFile'
In the first argument of `(<+<)', namely `sinkFile "testOutput"'
```

How do I convert sinkFile to a pipe which can be composed. is there a Strict vs. Lazy question?

Comment: Is `traverseTree` a function you defined?

Comment: it is a pipe (producer) which worked with

    testP1 = runPipe $ printer <+< traverseTree fn3

see my qeustion "breaddth-first traversal..."

Comment: I think you are mixing pipes and conduit code.

Answer (score 2):

the solution is straight-forward, writing a fileSink function, which appends to a file

```
fileSink = forever $ do 
inp <- await
liftIO $ appendFile "testOutput" ('\n' : show inp )
return ()
```

it might be more efficient to use a file handle and more practical, to pass the file name as an argument. using pipes is real easy!